# SQL Server Compatibility Level not working

Tags: sql-server, compatibility

We recently ran into an issue where the SQL our development team is writing is including new features from SQL Server 2012/2014 and it is being allowed by SQL Server 2014 running in [2008 compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-dbcmptlevel-transact-sql).

When I run this on the development server

```
EXEC SP_DBCMPTLEVEL '<insert db>'
GO

IF 1=1
    THROW 51000, 'values match', 1; 
GO
```

it returns this

> The current compatibility level is 100.
>  Msg 51000, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 5 
> values match

In production, the same SQL shows this:

> The current compatibility level is 100. 
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1,
>   Line 5 
> Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'.

We haven't yet upgraded our production SQL Server and are running into deployment issues. THROW is a keyword that is new to SQL Server 2012, so I expect the 2008 server to break on the syntax. It seems that the Compatibility Level is broken to me.

What can be done to prevent incompatible SQL from being allowed on the development environment?

Comment: You misunderstand compatibility level. Your code will run on SQL Server 2012 even in db with compatibility level 90, but it will not execute on SQL Server below 2012

Comment: The same thing is if you try to use lead/lag on SQL Server 2008 and below: you'll get an error. But you can use them on 2012 in context of database with CL 100 or even 90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.110).aspx )

> Compatibility level provides only partial backward compatibility with
>   earlier versions of SQL Server.

So, in the cited link you can see the list of what compatibility mode can affect.

To avoid this kind of problem my suggestion, based on experience is: development and production must be identical (as possible). If not, for example during a scheduled upgrade, at least test environment must be similar to production.

In the past we had to freeze release cicle for few days (except critical bugfix).